# Alert or message on specific option selected in select menu

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu

I have a select drop down menu. The menu is just for show and doesn't contribute anything to the form. However, I want option "b" to display an alert/message when it is selected/clicked BUT then I want option "a" selected after the user closes the alert (similar to `disabled`).

```
<select name="fake">
   <option name="a">a</option>
   <option name="b">b</option>
</select>
```

I found other javascript code, but nothing that suits my particular need.

EDIT

This is half way to what I need:

```
<select onchange="selectChangeHandler(this)">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
</select>
<script>
    function selectChangeHandler(selectNode) {
         if (selectNode.selectedIndex !== 2) {
             alert("I'm alert option!");
         }
    }
</script>
```

However, when the user selects option "b" and the alert is displayed, I want the option to revert back to option "a"

Comment: What did you find? What did you TRY? Can you use jQuery or some other library?

Comment: You'll get further faster using an _id_ attribute on the `<select>`. Putting a _name_ on `<option>` doesn't help much either. **[Here is the _DOM interface_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement)**. What have you tried?

Comment: `<select name="fake" onchange="if(this.value!='b'){alert('yes');>
   <option name="a">a</option>
   <option name="b">b</option>
</select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call a javascript function on call `onchange()` event.

**HTML**

```
<select name="fake" onchange="change(this);">
   <option value="a" name="a">a</option>
   <option value="b" name="b">b</option>
</select>
```

**javascript**,

```
<script>
function change(selBox) {
    for(var i, j = 0; i = selBox.options[j]; j++) {
        if(i.value == "b" && selBox.selectedIndex != 0) {
            alert("you've clicked b");
            selBox.selectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works fine in Chrome, however not as it should with IE. In IE I can select "b", it gives me the alert but the option remains selected. Then selecting "a" gives the alert again.

Comment: Bingo! You are a legend! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#chk').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() === 'a')
        alert("You Clicked a!");
});
```

where **chk** is the id of select element

if you are using name then

```
$('#chk').change(function(){
    if($(this).attr('name') === 'a')
        alert("You Clicked a!");
});
```

where **chk** is the id of select element

Comment: This question does not mention _jQuery_ or have it tagged (assuming `$` is _jQuery_ in your code)

Comment: No, im not using jQuery.
@ReNiShAR